# redirecting output of execvp into a file in C

Tags: c, file, redirect, execv

I don't know what I am doing wrong... but here is the snippet of code that is being executed:

```
if (fork() == 0)
    {       
             // child
        int fd = open(fileName, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);

        dup2(fd, 1);   // make stdout go to file

        execvp("ls","ls");
        close(fd);
            exit(0);
    }
if(wait(&status) == -1)
    {
        printf("ERROR REDIRECT\n");
    }
```

`fileName` gets created but there is nothing inside.What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You aren't calling `execvp` properly.

Comment: Did you try the exact same code without the `dup2`? It should print to standard output. This test could help focus on the problem.

Comment: Have you considered exec'ing the command "ls > $filename"?

Comment: @dbeer: That won't work, `exec...` functions expect executable files, not shell commands. You could use `system()` though...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is that the execvp doesn't work but since you don't handler errors you don't see it.

Try this:

```
char *const args[] = {"ls", NULL};
execvp(args[0], args);

/* If this is reached execvp failed. */

perror("execvp");
```

Alternatively you can use compound literals:

```
execvp("ls", (char *[]){"ls", NULL});
```

Second idea: try to run things normally, without redirect and see how it works.

Comment: I tried that and nothing gets printed... it seems that `execvp` gets executed succesfully.

Comment: @user1162954 - There is not a chance in the world your execvp is working.  Take cnicutar fix and your stuff will work.

Answer (score 1):

close fd before execvp.
because the code after execvp never runs unless execvp fails.