# redirect file as an input in C

Tags: c, redirect

I am trying to understand how I am supposed to execute the following command `wc < wc.in` in C without using any `exec()` function?

Comment: Why do you have to do it without `exec()`?

Comment: Does this have anything to do with [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070177/redirecting-output-of-execvp-into-a-file-in-c), because if it does, you should update that question instead of asking a new one.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using `system` instead.

Comment: +1: it works if the question means 'without calling `exec()` family functions directly in your code.  Otherwise, most likely `system()` uses an `exec()` family function behind the scenes - unless you're on a system where you can use the [`posix_spawn()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_spawn.html).  However, using that is _hard_ work; really hard work.